# Delete rows from Table, remove unpaid transaction

Tags: google-bigquery

What to do if you want to delete rows?

Use UNNEST -

> Error: Cannot access field hitId on a value with type
>   ARRAY< STRUCT< hitId STRING, isEntrance INT64, isExit INT64, ...>>

```
delete
FROM
xxxx.session_streaming_20161029
WHERE 
h.hitId = (
SELECT hitId
FROM xxxx.session_streaming_20161029, UNNEST(hits) as h
WHERE h.transaction.transactionId = '123456')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think that you actually want:

```
delete FROM xxxx.session_streaming_20161029
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM xxxx.session_streaming_20161029,
    UNNEST(hits) as h
  WHERE h.transaction.transactionId = '123456');
```

The idea is to match all rows where there is some transaction ID with value `'123456'`.

Edit: If the goal is to remove entries from `hits` with this transaction ID, and not to remove entire rows where `hits` contains the transaction ID, you can use `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE xxxx.session_streaming_20161029
SET hits =
  ARRAY(SELECT hit FROM UNNEST(hits)
        WHERE transaction.transactionId = '123456');
```

Comment: Run the query. Result - 57 rows affected - Deleted all rows in the table. Must - 1 rows affected

Comment: I'm still trying to understand what the intent of the query is. If it deletes all rows, then every row has a transaction with that ID. Are you trying to remove entries from `hits` that have that transaction ID without actually deleting the rows themselves? If so, I can change my answer to use `UPDATE` instead.

Comment: The goal - to remove the transaction. Or transactionRevenue=null and transaction.transactionId=null

Comment: See if the edit helps, but I still feel like there is a disconnect in what you are asking for.